# google play developers account showing less amount of downloads

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play-services, google-play-developer-api

My google play developers account showing less amount of downloads while analytics used in my app shows more.
currently my Google play account shows 100-150 downloads per day for my app
while my analytics shows 3000-4000 downloads per day.
There is Huge difference in both of this.
My analytics shows in conversion type following info:

Referrer :Other
Installs(last 7 days): 18,979

why my referrer is shown as other?
I have only launched my app on google play store and all this downloads are done through play store.
Why google play store developer accounts is not counting this downloads?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with google's servers. They can't show the real time download even in developer console.  They didn't fix it until too much time.

Comment: but my appis launched before 1 month and console is showing data of about 25 days of it after launch.but it is incorrect.have u faced this?

Comment: Yes. You can access statiycs third party tools like fabric. You cant fix to google